# Application working with COM hosting on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, com

I have an ASP.NET SignalR project, which I'm using to display windows app (let's call it worker) progress to web in live mode. The application is also a COM server, and I'm acessing it using *.dll file from the application's bundle. When I run my code in debug mode, it's working perfectly fine:

1. ASP.NET Web form is starting
2. My worker application is starting
3. I can see work progress both in worker window and browser.
4. If worker was launched before ASP.NET app, ASP.NET application is
   connecting to worker

Now, when I'm trying to host the ASP.NET application on IIS 7, my ASP.NET application - worker application pair is behaving weird:

When I start my ASP.NET application, worker app is also starting, but I can see it only in Task Manager and can't interact with it. If I start my worker before ASP.NET app, another worker app process is being created.

I've configured my ASP.NET app to impersonate as my computer's administrator

```
<identity impersonate="true" userName="admin" password="12345" />
```

So did I to IIS 7 application pool [Image](http://prntscr.com/1sz5lp)

I suppose it's configuration issue, as the same code (I mean connecting an interacting COM application) is working on WinForms applications.
Anyone, please, explain what is causing this behaviour and how to solve it!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected behavior. Even with impersonation you application will be running in IIS webserver user context. But is it really the issue? Does user need to interact with this application on desktop?

Comment: Actually, not really, but I would like to have interaction option for debugging use, so I'm wondering if I have chance to achieve this scenario.